# C++ iteration on first and last elements of array

Tags: c++, arrays

Let's say I have this array:

```
int oldv[10] = {16, 12, 24, 96, 45, 22, 18, 63, 47, 56};
```

and another one like

```
int newv[8];
```

and I want to fill new from alternating ends of `old` until a certain condition is met such that I'd have:

```
newv = [16, 56, 12, 47, 24, 63 ...]
```

Let's say I want to put in new only 3 numbers taken from old (that is: 16, 56, 12).
I've tried with the following for loop, but of course is not enough...

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    newv[i] = oldv[i*(sizeof(oldv)-1)];
```

Any help?

Comment: `new` is a keyword in C++. How did you get this code to compile?

Comment: @tobi303: I have just edited the question to hopefully make it a bit clearer.

Comment: @MartinBonner yep thanks

Comment: sorry, i was inventing the code while writing here. of course I cannot use new. let's call new_vect

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
int _old[10] = {16, 12, 24, 96, 45, 22, 18, 63, 47, 56};
int _new[8];

const int old_size = sizeof(_old)/sizeof(int);
const int new_size = sizeof(_new)/sizeof(int);

for (int i = 0; i < new_size; ++i)
{
    if (i % 2)
        _new[i] = _old[old_size - i / 2 - 1];
    else
        _new[i] = _old[i / 2];

    std::cout << _new[i] << " ";
}

std::cout << std::endl;
```

Returns `16 56 12 47 24 63 96 18`

[See it live](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMRFBueGdfYlAteE0)

Comment: @NickyC The logic looks wrong. But I dont understand what is wrong with sizeof array.

Comment: @static_cats if(1%2 == 1) case, you have to do  _new[i] = _old[sizeof(_old)/sizeof(_old[0]) - (i + 1)/2];

Comment: @MayurK `sizeof` gives you the array size in terms of bytes, not number of elements. Also, it takes some extra care to make sure there is no decay into pointer.

Comment: @NickyC: Oh! yes. It gives in bytes. But sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]) gives length of array right?

Comment: @MayurK Yes, or maybe. What if `array` is not really an array, but a pointer to an array? It is not the case here, but this mistake is very common.

Answer (score -2):

Enjoy.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main(int, char**)
{
    int oldv[] = { 16, 12, 24, 96, 45, 22, 18, 63, 47, 56 };
    int newv[8];
    size_t numbers_i_want = 3;

    size_t oldv_b = 0;
    size_t oldv_e = sizeof oldv / sizeof *oldv;
    size_t newv_e = sizeof newv / sizeof *newv;

    for(size_t i = 0;
        i != min(numbers_i_want, newv_e) && oldv_b != oldv_e;
        ++i)
    {
        newv[i] = (i % 2) ? oldv[--oldv_e] : oldv[oldv_b++];
    }

    copy(newv, newv + min(numbers_i_want, newv_e),
        ostream_iterator<decltype(*newv)>(cout, " "));
    return 0;
}
```